# Can the index number of a list itself be used as an integer in Python?

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary

I am doing this code wars kata https://www.codewars.com/kata/57eb8fcdf670e99d9b000272/train/python

you have to return the highest scoring word within a string. letters are scored based on position in the alphabet

```
a =1, z= 26
```

I've created a list :

```
alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
```

I want to iterate through the words, which will be in the string (x) passed as a parameter, and if the letter being checked is in the alphabet list, which it of course will be,  then to a sperate variable: score, increment score by the number at which the current letter being checked is indexed within the alphabet list.

Is it possible to use list indexes in this way?

Here's my code soo far:

```
def high(x):
    alphabet = []
    scores = [] # ignore
    score = 0 
    for letter in range(97,123):
        alphabet.append(chr(letter))
    word_list = x.split()
    for word in word_list: 
        for letter in word: 
            if letter in alphabet:
                score += # find way to use alphabet list index number as integer here
```

Thanks.

Comment: For the web site questions, please include the original link for the problem.

Comment: have a look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate

Comment: Does the list actually need to exist at al - what is wrong with using `ord(letter)-96` which will give you a value between 1 and 26 for each of a to z respectively.
to test if the letter is actually a letter use `letter.islapha()`

Comment: @AlanJP - please check my post. (haven't seen the link yet.) Well - you will need to modify a bit to meet that's `max score word` req. it should be fine.

Comment: @DanielHao I updated my question to include the link

Comment: @TonySuffolk66 beginner python learner here but thanks for the reply will look into your way of doing it

Comment: @AlanJP  - I think you `accept` another Post, not mine.  (that's perfect fine ~ :-)

Comment: @AlanJP. Have added an answer that expands on my suggestion - no need for a list of letters at all. Take a look.

Comment: @TonySuffolk66 thanks a lot will look over your answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. `alphabet.index(letter) + 1` will give you what you want.

Comment: Raises a ValueError if there is no such item.

Comment: Assumptions included inclusion: “if the letter being checked is in the alphabet list, which it of course will be”

Comment: `string.ascii_lowercase` is an improvement over hardcoding the English alphabet by hand. I.e., `string.ascii_lowercase.index(letter) + 1`.

Answer (score 1):

@AlanJP, would you like to try this program:

```py
# simple word scoring program

import string

characters = string.ascii_lowercase

ranking = {c: i for i, c in enumerate(characters, 1)}

#print(ranking)

word_list = 'abba is great'.split()

for word in word_list:
    score = 0       # reset the score for each incoming word
    for char in word:
        score += ranking[char]
    print(word, score)
```

Output:

```
abba 6
is 28
great 51
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and dictionary `score` to keep track of each letter and its score. Notice that the input string is lowercased - I assume that upper- and lowercase letters are scored the same.

```
alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
score = dict(zip(list(alphabet), [i + 1 for i in range(len(alphabet))]))

x = 'aB, c'
score = sum([score[c] for c in list(x.lower()) if c in score])
print(score)
# 6
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see the list of letters isn't needed at all :

```
import string

def high(x):
    score = 0
    for word in x.split():
         for letter in word: 
             if letter in string.ascii_lowercase:
                score += ord(letter)-96
    return score
```

or even simpler :

```
import string

def high(x):
    # Sum expression on multiple lines for clarity
    return sum( ord(letter)-96 
                  for word in x.split() 
                      for letter in word
                          if letter in string.ascii_lowercase)
```

Answer (score 0):

index() you're going also want to +1 to account for index [0]

```
# vowels list
vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'i', 'u']

# index of 'e' in vowels
index = vowels.index('e')
print('The index of e:', index)
```